# Jump to where insert mode was entered?

Tags: mark

`` `. `` seems to take me to where I last left insert mode, but I would like to jump to where my cursor was when I entered insert mode last.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't yanked or changed text since your last insertion, then you can use the `` `[ `` mark (see [docs](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%60%5B)), which gets you back "to the first character of the previously changed or yanked text."

By the way, [`` `. ``](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%60.) will track your last *change*, not necessarily an insertion, a deletion, indent or format operation would also reset this mark.

The [`` `^ ``](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%60%5E) mark is the one tracking your last insertion. (But, as you mentioned, it will go back to where your cursor ended, not started.)

See also:

- [`:changes`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%3Achanges), which shows you a list of recent changes, including insertions;
- the [`g;`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#g%3B) command, which lets you jump back to previous positions in that list (and corresponding `g,` to jump forward.)

Comment: This was probably the hardest markdown I ever had to type, given the number of `s (couldn't have more than one on the same line) and [ is special too... Phew!

Comment: I just used `<code>` tags. I tried <code>`[</code> earlier but it didn't work for me, i guess I'd accidentally made an additional change in-between bc it is actually what I want.

Comment: @theonlygusti If you have another ` on the same line, that will confuse it... Preview window was terribly helpful here!